# ExactTarget JourneyBuilder custom activity can't activate after Jan 16 update

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

After the January 2016 update was pushed out by ExactTarget, we can no longer get our JourneyBuilder Custom Activities to update.

When we go to "Activate" an interaction, we get a response that says:

```
1 errors. Resolve errors in the canvas before testing or activation.
Activity REST-1 of type REST has an argument execute which is not a valid argument
```

We haven't made any changes to our Custom Activity (v1.0 api), so I assume that this broke due to an ExactTarget change.

In our config, the **arguments.execute** property looks like this:

```
...
"execute": {
    "verb": "POST",
    "url": "https://example.com/notify",
    "body": "{}",
    "header": "",
    "format": "json",
    "useJwt": false,
    "timeout": 10000
},
...
```

Has anyone experienced this (and solved)?

Comment: Please can you provide URL to your config.json file? I think I may know what the issue is.

Comment: Our config.json is here:
https://pfllink-dev-awrowse.azurewebsites.net/journeybuilder/config.json

Comment: can you try changing `verb` to `method` and `header` to `headers` and also remove the `format` name/value pair.

Comment: I think I've narrowed the issue down to my "body". If I include any sort of template values; i.e. {{Contact.Default.Email}} or {{Contact.ID}}, the interaction will fail to activate. The funny thing is that any interactions that I had previously activated still work and send the correctly resolved template data during the POST.  @eliotharper, I see in some of your other posts you use inArguments with execute. Do those work for you? They should come across in the POST body, correct?

Comment: One more update. Looks like the issue with templated fields (ie. {{Contact.ID}}) isn't limited to the 'body' parameter. If I include this in an inArg we are not able to Activate the interaction.

Comment: OK, so I've just tested our Custom Activity and guess what? We get the same error when Activating an Interaction. Go figure. @andy, let me know if you manage to get an answer to this one. I'll start asking for answers too.

Comment: We've been in touch with ExactTarget; they recognize this as a bug and are working on a 'priority fix'; although there is no indication as to when it will be ready. They also didn't have any suggestions for a work around. At the moment we are dead in the water.

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed (by testing) that this is fixed in the 19 March 2016 release.

When you published an Interaction that included a Custom Activity, previously you received the error:

> Activity REST-1 of type REST has an argument execute which is not a valid argument and were unable to publish the Interaction.

Marketing Cloud acknowledged this bug and released a [long anticipated] fix for this issue in the March release.

I have successfully published an Interaction with a Custom Activity (and no longer receive the error) and the Interaction now appears to be working correctly; Contacts enter the Interaction and the Custom Activity functions as expected.

Comment: Can you add some more detail about how you verified? This answer does not really have enough content to be justified as being more than a comment, currently.

Comment: I meant you should [edit] this information into your answer.

Comment: I'm having exactly this same error working with the create case / update case example. **"Activity REST-2 of type REST has an argument caseID which is not a valid argument"** This was supposed to be fixed last 19 March 2016 release, but in my case is still failing. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Hello Sergio, this should work, please can you send a link to your config.json file?